# How to wait for catch error in useMutation onError from axios interceptors?

Tags: reactjs, axios, formik, interceptor, react-query

I am trying to handle server side error on useMutation

I have signup.jsx page. onSubmit, it will do register the user or return error 'Email id already exists' from server side

My interceptors return error successfully

**axios-utils.js (interceptor)**

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    console.log('RESPONSE CALLED')
    console.log(response)
    return response;
}, (error) => {
    console.log('INTERCEPTOR RESPONSE ERROR')
    return Promise.reject(error);
})
```

**apiAuth.js**

```
async function AddUser(user) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post("/Auth/register", user)
        console.log(response)
        return response
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Register call error')
        console.log(error.response.status)    //return 451
        console.log(error.response.data)      //return Email ID already exists
        return await Promise.reject(error)
    }
}

export const apiAuthRegister = () => {

  return (
    useMutation({
        mutationKey: ['authRegister'],
        mutationFn:  (user) =>  AddUser(user),
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            console.log('REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY')
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log('REGISTER FAILED')
            console.log(error)   //it shows AxiosError object successfully
            return error.response.data   //How to get this error msg in signup.jsx onSubmit?
        }
    })
  )
}
```

Once OnSubmit called `mutate(values)`, it's not waiting for the error msg from `useMutation`, I can see the error message When I click again the submit button, then it goes to `if(registerMutate?.isError)` (apiAuth.js)

I tried also `mutateAsync(values)`. results are same

**signup.jsx**

```
const SignUp = () => {  
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(initialValue)

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('USE EFFECT CALLED')
    },[errorMsg])

    const registerMutate = apiAuthRegister();

    return(
        <Formik
            onSubmit={  (values, formik) => {
              console.log("On Submit Called");
              registerMutate.mutate(values)

              //skipping the below code
              if(registerMutate?.isLoading) return console.log('loading...') //not trigger
              
              if(registerMutate?.isError){   //not triggering at first time click submit button
                  const newErrorMsg = {...errorMsg}
                  const data = registerMutate?.error.response.data
                  newErrorMsg.emailID = data
                  setErrorMsg(newErrorMsg)
                  console.log(errorMsg)
                  formik.setErrors({
                    emailID:errorMsg.emailID
                  });
                  
                  //it prints at second time submitting button
                  console.log(registerMutate?.error?.response?.data)
              } 

              if(registerMutate?.isSuccess) return console.log('success...'+ registerMutate.data)  //not trigger
              
            }}

        >
        //... elements

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `apiAuthRegister` to accept an callback for on error, maybe something like this:

Update the function:

```js
export const apiAuthRegister = ({ onError }) => {

  return (
    useMutation({
        mutationKey: ['authRegister'],
        mutationFn:  (user) =>  AddUser(user),
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            console.log('REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY')
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log('REGISTER FAILED')
            console.log(error)   //it shows AxiosError object successfully

            onError(error.response.data) // call the callback with the error instead of returning it
        }
    })
  )
}
```

Then use it like this:

```js
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(initialValue)
  const registerMutate = apiAuthRegister({
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log("ON ERROR CALLBACK CALLED");
      setErrorMsg((prevErrorMsg) => ({ ...prevErrorMsg, emailID: error }));
      console.table(errorMsg);
    },
  });
```

Comment: thanks, it works, sorry for delay reply. I usually work at night. I go through this [link tkdodo.eu](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#mutate-or-mutateasync). really amazing docs